# Razor pages hosting on nginx reverse proxy not showing after dotnet publish

Tags: asp.net, razor, nginx-reverse-proxy, vps

I have an Ubuntu VPS running nginx that reverse proxies my Razor pages.  So far the site loads at https but when i edit the index.cshtml file, running dotnet build and publish and restarting service and nginx, the new changes still doesnt show in the browser.  I tried ctrl+f5 to and clearing caches but no luck. What am i missing?  Thank you.

Added this to Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

and added package to VPS:
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation

Tried to rebuild:
dotnet clean, build, publish
restarted NewApp.service (sudo systemctl restart NewApp)
restarted nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to delete the NewApp.dll from the publish folder before rebuilding.  I'm closing this thread I hope my issue helps other noobs like me.